# java returning null when trying to retrieve file from jar file

Tags: java, jar, nullpointerexception, java-7, filenotfoundexception

The jar files are generated during build time and contain xml files that need to be read during run time. I am using Java webstart which downloads these jar file to a local folder. the local  path to where the jar is stored is: 
    C:\Users\username\Desktop\Project\jars

This folder contains multiple jar files. What i am trying to achieve is for the code to locate a particular jar based on a filename it contains and read an xml file contained in the jar. The xml file is located in a folder called xmlfiles in the jar but this is returning null.

Note: this used to work with previous versions of Java 3-5 but after our migration to Java 7, this method returns null. This is the portion of the method throwing the exception

```
private InputStream Jar(String _filename) throws  IOException
    {
      String path = "xmlfiles/" + _filename;
      InputStream content = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(path) 
        System.out.println("loaded xml);

    }
```

I have also tried getting the URL and printing out the string, but get a fileNotfound Exception

```
URL path = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource(url);
```

I have tried various solutions with similar question on here but none of the solution can locate the file (returnin null or file not found)
[InputStream from jar-File returns always null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15830532/inputstream-from-jar-file-returns-always-null)
[Parse XML File within Jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15535153/parse-xml-file-within-jar)
[Accessing a file inside a .jar file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8258244/accessing-a-file-inside-a-jar-file)

Comment: Are these jars in your classpath at runtime?

Comment: @fge yes they are in the classpath

Comment: Well then simply do a resource lookup, no need to name the jar; or do you have files with the same path in different jars?

Comment: @fge The path is the same for all the generated jars but the filename is different based on _filename

Comment: That is a very bad idea! Basically this means you cannot use a resource lookup but have to walk all the classloader URLs and find the suitable jar before opening it and fetching the file... Make your life more simple: have the path be different for all your resources; then a simple resource lookup will be enough.